# Authorize holding click on QSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

I created a `QSpinBox` for my application, but when I let the mouse pressed on the buttons on the right of the inbox (to upgrade or downgrade the value) it only changes value one time.
However, the functionality works when I create a `QDoubleSpinBox`. I didn't succeed to find on which method work to grant "auto-repeat" to my `QSpinBox`.

Comment: Can you show some code? How do you create it? Which version of Qt are you using? From the docs it seems as rhis should work out of the box. Maybe try calling `setAccelerated(true)` on it?

Comment: I create the Widget with Qt Designer, there is no really code to show. The version of Qt used is the 4.8. I tried the `setAccelerated(true)` fiew days ago, it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by auto repeat..?

Comment: Auto-repeat is for me the fact that when you let the mouse pressed on the button, the value in the box increaaaase until you release the mouse. Actually when pressed the button continually during 10sc, the value increase once only.

Comment: That sounds a bit weird, AFAIK QSpinBox/QDoubleSpinBox by default do that auto repeat thing.